# PHP setcookie() not working

Tags: php, cookies

On one page I have something like this

```
setcookie('user', 'value' ,6000, '/', 'mydomain.co.uk');
```

On the subsequent page I have

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

I can see all the automatically generated ones, like `PHPSESSID` but I cannot see `user`.

If I do `echo setcookie('user', 'value' ,6000, '/', 'mydomain.co.uk');` it returns `true`. So I'm not sure why I can't see it.

I have tried a lot of different ideas, but nothing has worked. Also, I have using .htaccess to redirect all requests via one page `index.php` not sure if this is doing anything.

Comment: You might find [`new Cookie($name)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L51) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
setcookie('user', 'value' ,time() + 6000, '/', 'mydomain.co.uk');
```

The expires Parameter needs to be a timestamp. `6000` as a timestamp is in the past and therefore removes the cookie.

Comment: Added note: the expires parameter can be set to 0 which basically makes the cookie expire at the end of the session. http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
setcookie('user', 'value' ,6000, '/', '.mydomain.co.uk');
```

Check your brower's cookies.  Some browsers (firefox and chrome) have addons that allow you to see cookies as they come in so you can debug.

EDIT:  The problem is 6000.  That is wrong.
use this: `time() + 6000`

Comment: Yeah I've been using a Chrome add-on but resorted to var_dumping $_COOKIE when it wasn't appearing in there either. I've tried using '.mydomain.co.uk' but it's still not working :(